# Mac OS 10.6 vs Chrome - video on youtube is not displayed

Tags: mac, google-chrome, flash, macbook-pro, youtube

After starting my Mac OS 10.6 from sleeping mode are not displayed video on youtube. I use Google Chrome.

Does anyone the same problem or tip, what caused this? It's annoying me still restart Macbook for fixing that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update flash player. Are you you using original Macbook or a hackintosh?

Comment: I use Macbook Pro. What's the best way to update flash (I am new on Mac)?

Comment: Go to adobe site download latest flash version.

Comment: Here is the link. http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: ok, so currently the videos on youtube are working. Thanks!